# Saving loop results in array or txt-file

Tags: python, arrays, loops

So I have a .txt-file with a list of countries like:

```
Japan
Faroe Islands
Libya
South Ossetia
Tunisia
...
```

For all countries I now wish to add: "What is the capital of". So what I have done is just:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('countries.txt')

countries = np.array(data)

for country in countries:
    x = 'What is the capital of ' + country
```

And then it just runs through every country and adds the above sentence before the country name. But since I'm pretty new to Python, I don't know how to save my loops into and array, or .txt file (doesn't matter). Now it just returns (if I print or something) one line at a time, and doesn't "add everything up" so to speak.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `x = 'What is the capital of ' + element` neither prompts for an answer or even runs (because `element` is not defined). Please can you edit the question with the code you're actually using and what you have tried in terms of saving responses?

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake... The "element" should be "country" of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after something like this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('countries.txt')

countries = np.array(data)

questions = []
for country in countries:
    questions += 'What is the capital of ' + country + '?'

# Do any operation on questions (which will look like ['What is the capital of Japan?', 'What is the capital of Faroe Islands?', ..., 'What is the capital of <country name here>?']
```

Alternatively, you can write all the questions to a text file by doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('countries.txt', header=None)

countries = np.array(data)

with open("Questions.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for country in countries[0]:
        question = 'What is the capital of ' + country + '?'

        outfile.write(question) # or use print(question, file=outfile)
```

Comment: I think it is the last suggestion I'm looking for. However, my output file is gibberish, i.e.: hú ú0úhú úhú0ú úhú0ú úhú Õ ú0úhú ú Õ ú0ú úhú0úx and so on :) Which I don't understand, because if I use the print command there is no problem at all.

Comment: What does it appear as? hard to help if I don't know

Comment: This is why: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray`. Try using a debugger or using intermediate print statements to look at the variables mid way through execution. For example, `print(countries)` right after you set up the `np.array` will output something messy!

Comment: Things to note: the first element is missing (ie Japan), also it is a two dimensional array.

Comment: If I use the print statement right after the np.array I get an array with all the country names, as I think I should get?

Comment: The debugger didn't find anything either. Perhaps it is a character issue, utf-8 or something ? :/

Comment: One note, include in your pandas import line `header=None`. Otherwise, you will lose your first line of data (unless you do actually have a header)

Comment: Please see my edited answer for the final solution you're after. If this helped you please mark the answer accepted and/or vote